# Run maven test in parallel without waiting for sibling module dependencies

Tags: java, maven, testing, build, parallel-builds

I have a multi-module maven project in which the modules have quite a few dependencies between them. I have tried running my tests in parallel, but since the modules are not very well thought off and are highly dependent on each other, I basically have no time gain, since they still end up executing sequentially.

Now, before running the tests altogether I have a phase where I build the project so that I may apply other static analysis tools in parallel to my testing.

My question is: Given that my modules are already compiled, can I not tell maven to run tests in parallel using these precompiled classes and not wait for dependant modules to run their tests first?
E.g. currently if I have a module A depending on module B, module B would execute all its tests first before A could start. Since I have A and B already built, I have no need to keep this limitation.

The way I run tests currently is something like:
`mvn -f project-parent/pom.xml surefire:test` where project parent is a module parenting all my other modules. I have ommited profiles and other parameters for brevity.

Thanks!

Edit: I am trying to avoid class/suite level parallelization at this point using junit or surefire and would just like to test modules in a parallel way.

Comment: Why do you build your modules first before you run the tests? Why not just build everything with `mvn clean install`?

Comment: @JFabianMeier I do something on the lines of a clean install but skip tests initially so that I may run the tests in parallel with other code analysis tools afterwords.

Comment: If they are _highly dependent on each other_, either refactor the bits that are dependent or remove the dependencies if the are unsued. As you already told, aiming to parallize a reactor build which is essentially a `List` instead of a somewhat balanced `Tree` does not work.

Comment: That's a feature not a bug. If module B fails its tests, then Module A will probably fail its tests as well because module B isn't functional. You will have extra noise in your test results that could make it harder for you or your team to identify the true issue.

Comment: @JohnBrandli completely understandable, and I'm sure useful in many scenarios - but is it also something one could disable? :)

Answer (score 4):

`Child` tests can pass but `Parent` tests fail. This might be because `Child` requires `Parent` but most of its tests *mock* `Parent` on the assumption it works! If this happens *in parallel and out of sequence*, I don't think Maven would know what to do. You are hoping that Maven can be an entire CI pipeline when really it's just a build tool.

However:

If your tests are slow enough for you to raise this SO question, then they might be integration tests that can be extracted into new modules (`<module>-tests`).

```
A -> A-tests
A -> B
     B -> B-tests
     B -> C
          C -> C-tests
```

This means the A, B and C `src/test/*` complete quickly and can be run "as normal" and the slower `<module>-tests` do not depend on each other meaning Maven can parallelise them with nothing more than `mvn test -TC`.

Answer (score 0):

- [Skip compiling the tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html)

> If you absolutely must, you can also use the `maven.test.skip` property to skip compiling the tests. `maven.test.skip` is honored by `Surefire`, `Failsafe` and the `Compiler` Plugin.

```
   mvn -T 8 -f project-parent/pom.xml surefire:test -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: Well the entire point is that of not skipping tests :) I want to run them but without having to wait for dependant modules to run their tests first. Maybe I am missinterpreting your answer though. If I do this, will my tests be run in a parallel way that does not care about inter-module dependencies?

Comment: Your requirement is o skip compile and run tests in parallel. Whether all 8 threads work on the same module or different module does not matter as the work done by the 8 threads is same

Comment: Well from my understanding (and testing) the -T parameter configuration described above will never build/test a single module on 8 threads, it will allow building independent modules / modules with already fullfiled dependencies, 1 per thread. As per: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3 where it states: This build-mode analyzes your project's dependency graph and schedules modules that can be built in parallel according to the dependency graph of your project.